# Will I loose my privileges when the site graduates?

Tags: support, reputation

I have noticed that graduated sites have much higher reputation thresholds  for privileges, for instance the "trusted user" privilege goes from 4k on a beta site to 20k rep on a full site.  I currently have 4k rep, am I correct in presuming that I will no longer have this privilege (along with quite a few others) when the site graduates?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Unless you get 20k before the site graduates ;)